# Java Stack becomes empty for some reason

Tags: java, android, api

I'm working on an Android app that is going to call the DarkSky weather API (I have redacted my API key here for obvious reasons). My problem comes when I parse the JSON data and push it to a stack I named dataStack. At the time of pushing the stack I log its size and it shows correctly. However when my code reaches the buildGraph() method, the stack is now empty and all my data has disappeared. What causes the stack to empty?

EDIT: As of 30 minutes after posting I found a workaround. I am now returning the String and parsing it in my MainActivity Android class. However, I still do not know why the stack was being deleted. I would love to know :)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    TextView progressLabel;

    GraphView graph;

    JSONObject jsonObject;

    static Stack<DataPoint> dataStack = new Stack<>(); // stack for graph data points

    static final String API_URL = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/API_KEY/42.3611,-71.0570,"; // #TODO: delete API key before comitting to GitHub
    static final String URL_TAIL = "?exclude=currently,flags,hourly"; // end of URL
    static final long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L; // current UNIX time
    static long unixTime = currTime;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        progressLabel = findViewById(R.id.progressLabel);

        graph =  findViewById(R.id.graph);
    }

    public void loadResults(View view) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) { // 7 API calls for each of 7 days
            new APICall().execute();
            unixTime -= 86400; // subtract 24 hours in UNIX time
            dataStack.size();
        }
        buildGraph(); // after all data is gathered, build a graph using it
    }

    private void buildGraph() {
// #TODO: Method to build graph
        Log.i("STACK pop", String.valueOf(dataStack.size())); 
    }


    class APICall extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> { // Extend AsyncTask so we don't hijack the main UI thread

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Do stuff before executing the AsyncTask
            progressLabel.setText("Fetching Data");
        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            // Execute background task here


            try {
                final String FULL_URL = API_URL + unixTime + URL_TAIL; // build the full URL with latest time
                URL url = new URL(FULL_URL); // URL for the API call
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // connection to URL
                try {
                    // tools for reading API results
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    // accumulate results
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }

                    bufferedReader.close(); // always close buffered reader

                     return stringBuilder.toString(); // return results
                }
                finally {
                    // inside a finally block so that no matter what we always end a connection that has been started
                    urlConnection.disconnect(); // end the connection

                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                Log.e("ERROR", ex.getMessage(), ex);
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            // Do stuff after we're finished executing

            if (response == null) {
                response = "AN ERROR HAS OCCURRED";
            }
            else {
                try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(response); // create object from our response
                    JSONArray arr = jsonObject.getJSONObject("daily").getJSONArray("data"); // get data Array
                    String arrString = arr.getString(0); // full String
                    String[] splitString = arrString.split(","); // split String into array by comma


                    String time = splitString[0].substring(8); // time is the first index of the array, use substring to cutout unecessary info
                    String temp = splitString[11].substring(18);

                    dataStack.push(new DataPoint(Integer.valueOf(time), Float.valueOf(temp))); // push our data onto the stack as a DataPoint

                    Log.i("STACK push", String.valueOf(dataStack.toString()));

                    response = "Data received"; // display this to user
                }
                catch(Exception ex) {
                    response = "ERROR DURING JSON PARSING";
                }

            }

            progressLabel.setText(response);
            // parse data here
            Log.i("INFO", response);

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack is empty because result isn't in yet. The issue is with your `loadResults()`.

```
    public void loadResults(View view) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) { // 7 API calls for each of 7 days
            new APICall().execute();
            unixTime -= 86400; // subtract 24 hours in UNIX time
            dataStack.size();
        }
        buildGraph(); // after all data is gathered, build a graph using it
    }
```

You issued the `new APICall().execute();` to request data and update the `dataStack` and you expect to get the `dataStack` results 'immediately' inside the same function `loadResults()`? It's not possible.

One solution is to remove the `buildGraph()` in `loadResults()` to inside `onPostExecute()`.